# Link the document with one another

Tags: 2013, document-library, enterprise-search

I need to link one document with another document based on the text in the document. let me try to explain the exact scenario. 
For example I have three documents in Word or PDF format. Lets say Document 1 has word 'Article 1' , 
Document 2  has the word 'Article 2' and the document 3 has the word 'Paragraph 2'.

I want build the solution to provide search functionality to user that if the user enter any of the word then it should returns all the three document links to the user and then user can click any of the link to go to that particular document.

Is SharePoint 2013 provide out of the box functionality for this or need to build a custom solution.

If needs to build a custom solution then what kind of solution it will be.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So you want synonyms?
SharePoint 2013 provides this functionality.